# Removing linked list nodes

Tags: c#, beginner, linked-list

I have this code to remove nodes in a linked list which have odd values. This works well but I want to fine tune it for better reading. Can you please suggest improvements?

```
public class MyLinkedList
{
    public int data;
    public MyLinkedList next;

    public MyLinkedList(int v)
    {
        this.data = v;
    }

    //public void add(int i)
    //{
    //    this.next = new MyLinkedList(i);
    //    this.next.next = null;
    //}

    public void printLL()
    {
        MyLinkedList mmm = this;
        while (mmm != null)
        {
            Console.Write(mmm.data);
            Console.Write("->");
            mmm = mmm.next;
        }
    }
}

public static void deleteOdd(ref MyLinkedList mll)
{
    MyLinkedList head, previous, curr;
    head = mll;
    while (head.data % 2 != 0)
    {
        head = head.next;
    }
    mll = head;

    previous = head;
    curr = previous.next;

    while (curr != null)
    {
        if (curr.data % 2 != 0)
        {
            previous.next = curr.next;
            curr = previous.next;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = previous.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyLinkedList myll1 = new MyLinkedList(1); MyLinkedList myll2 = new MyLinkedList(3);
        MyLinkedList myll3 = new MyLinkedList(4); MyLinkedList myll4 = new MyLinkedList(4);
        MyLinkedList myll5 = new MyLinkedList(5); MyLinkedList myll6 = new MyLinkedList(6);
        MyLinkedList myll7 = new MyLinkedList(5); MyLinkedList myll8 = new MyLinkedList(6);
        MyLinkedList myll9 = new MyLinkedList(6); MyLinkedList myll10 = new MyLinkedList(9);
        MyLinkedList myll11 = new MyLinkedList(11); MyLinkedList myll12 = new MyLinkedList(12);

        myll1.next = myll2; myll2.next = myll3; myll3.next = myll4; myll4.next = myll5;
        myll5.next = myll6; myll6.next = myll7; myll7.next = myll8; myll8.next = myll9;
        myll9.next = myll10; myll10.next = myll11; myll11.next = myll12; myll12.next = myll12; myll12.next = null;


    myll1.printLL();
    Console.WriteLine();
    deleteOdd(ref myll1);
    Console.WriteLine();
    myll1.printLL();
}
```

Comment: `MyLinkedList mmm = this` Using nonsensical variable names complicates things. Calling it `currentNode` or something similar would've helped tremendously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lack of abstraction

`MyLinkedList` isn't really a linked list - it's a single *node*. The lack of an encapsulating list class makes it difficult to provide reusable methods such as `Add`, `Remove` and `Contains`, and the lack of such methods (among others) makes your linked list difficult and error-prone to use.

- `MyLinkedList` is a misleading name. Something like `MyLinkedListNode` would be more accurate.
- Creating a proper linked list class that 'manages' its nodes allows you to create general-purpose methods like `Add` and `Remove`, and it can implement `IEnumerable` and other useful interfaces (this makes it usable with `foreach` and `Linq` methods). With such methods, removing odd entries will be easier. Without them, your class is practically useless.
- Collection classes are almost always generic - this makes them usable with different data-types.
- `printLL` not only ties your class to the console (which VisualMelon already pointed out), it also doesn't need to be part of the class (it's using public data), and it shouldn't be part of the class because it doesn't contribute to the core responsibilities (storing data).
- All data in your class is public. That's often a bad idea, as it allows any code to modify it, and indeed, it's easy to create a problematic state: `a.next = b; b.next = a;` (try calling `a.printLL()` or `removeOdd(ref a);` on that).

If you're reinventing a wheel for educational purposes, then don't forget to study existing wheels (such as [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)).

### Other notes

- The use of `ref` here is a hack. Consider the following situation: `MyLinkedList b = a; deleteOdd(ref b); a.printLL();` - `a` can still contain odd values. You don't need this if you create a proper linked list class.
- Squashing multiple statements on a single line makes code harder to read. It also doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that this linked list is cumbersome to use. It would be easier if it offered a constructor that accepted an `IEnumerable<T>`. And if it had an `Add` method, you could use collection initializer syntax: `var myList = new MyLinkedList { 1, 3, 5 };`.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on the logical benefits of a 'proper' linked list interface.

Comment: Thanks a ton Pieter! This is exactly what I wanted to know. I was missing the  abstraction pillar of OOP which confused me with both add and print methods.

Answer (score 4):

### Simple Commentary

- The MSDN provides some [naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions), the relevant bit being that `public` members should be `ProperCamelCase` (e.g. `Data`, not `data`).
- Public Members, and types, should ideally have at least minimal inline documentation (`\\\`) to make it perfectly clear how to consume the API.
- It's usually for the best to strip out old (commented) code. It has a habit of not being maintained and becoming incompatable with the code that is there. It also adds clutter.
- For 'export' code, it's rarely useful to have methods which explicitly write to the console: much more useful to have something that writes to an abstract `TextWriter` (which can take `Console.Out` or a `StreamReader`), or that just returns a string. These give the consumer many more options.
- `deleteOdd(ref MyLinkedList)` probably can't cope with empty lists (being passed them or returning them).
- `printLL` isn't a great variable name: what is "LL"? It's a member of `MyLinkedList`, so the "LL" bit is redundant; I spect a while trying to work out if it was something to do with printing left to right or something.
- `mmm` isn't a great variable name either: I can only assume it was *meant* to be `mll`!

---

### Alternative implementation

Below are some methods which just about tally with yours, but using `LinkedList<T>`, and incorporating some of the suggestions above.

I don't know if you have a particular reason for needing a custom LinkedList implementation (not suggested by the code), but you can implement your methods tidily with .NET's built in [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx), which could be argued to provide a nicer API. Crucially, it wraps up a linked list of [`LinkedListNode<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx)s under a `LinkedList<T>`, which allows some (illusion of) separation of concerns, and spares you having to keep track of the head of the list explicitly. It also allows you to have an 'empty' list, which is good.

#### Delete Odd

This method is considerably shorter than before, and doesn't require a `ref` parameter. This works with empty lists. This is a much more understandable implementation, and much harder to 'get wrong', because of the API for `LinkedList<T>`.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Removes odd elements from a LinkedList of integers
/// </summary>
public static void DeleteOdd(LinkedList<int> ll)
{
    LinkedListNode<int> cur = ll.First; // grab first node

    while (cur != null)
    {
        var next = cur.Next; // make a note of the next node (will be null if cur is the last element)

        if (cur.Value % 2 != 0)
        {
            ll.Remove(cur); // remove the current node if odd
        }

        cur = next; // advance to the next node
    }
}
```

#### `printLL`

Here are two possible alternatives, which don't depend explicitly on `Console`: one just produces a string, the other prints to a `TextWriter` (sadly there is no better interface). These are both extension methods for `LinkedList<T>`, but there is no particular need for this.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Renders a linked list as a string
/// </summary>
public static string Render<T>(this LinkedList<T> ll)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var e in ll)
    {
        sb.Append(e.ToString());
        sb.Append("->");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

/// <summary>
/// Prints a linked list to a TextWriter, optionally appending a NewLine
/// </summary>
public static void Print<T>(this LinkedList<T> ll, TextWriter textWriter, bool newLine = true)
{
    foreach (var e in ll)
    {
        textWriter.Write(e.ToString());
        textWriter.Write("->");
    }

    if (newLine)
        textWriter.WriteLine();
}
```

I wouldn't necessarily condone having the `newLine` parameter being optional, or indeed being there at all: this is just for illustration of some options. It would probably be better to have both `Print` and `PrintLine` if you need both.

#### Example usage

Note the nicer API for building a `LinkedList<T>`.

```cs
private static void ExampleUsage()
{
    LinkedList<int> ll = new LinkedList<int>();
    ll.AddLast(1);
    ll.AddLast(2);
    ll.AddLast(3);
    ll.AddLast(4);
    ll.AddLast(5);

    Console.WriteLine(ll.Render());
    ll.Print(Console.Out);
    DeleteOdd(ll);
    Console.WriteLine(ll.Render());
    ll.Print(Console.Out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed answer VisualMelon!

Perhaps I wasn't clear but what I actually meant to ask was tuning the logic to look more elegant, not just formatting the code.

I want to understand if the underlying implementation works the way I have coded. I mean, if I can use the framework's LinkedList type, there is no point in implementing custom code at all.

However, I do like the revamped print function which is a great example of independence from the console.

TLDR, am I allowed to use framework's datatype in interviews avoiding this hassle in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: @ShreeHarsha I couldn't say if it is allowed, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't, and more so if it wasn't clearly specified! I'd have thought that writing code which works with existing data structures would be a useful skill to demonstrate (and showing awareness of the standard libraries can never be a bad thing). Hopefully the shorter `DeleteOdd` shows how the logic can be made cleaner with a 'more substantial' linked list API, which maybe helps answer your underlying question!

Answer (score 1):

### Naming of variables:

- Consider the reader who has never seen your code (which will presumably be the position you will be in if you have to revisit this code in some 6 months time). What about these names: `public MyLinkedList(int v)` (what is v?) and `MyLinkedList mmm = this;` what is `mmm`? And again you've named the int variable `data`. What is data?
- And my pet peeve `MyLinkedList myll1` - now is that an 'L' or an 'I' capitalised or is that a numeral '1'? It's very hard to tell and I would counsel against doing it.
- Secondly, the name “LinkedList” has certain connotations. Is it in fact a derivative class of linked List? I'm just saying that the naming of the class has considerable ambiguity, and that is the enemy of writing lucid code. If someone receives an instance of your linked list, are they entitled to expect that they can call `AddFirst` method on it without issues? A better name would be appropriate to reflect this.
- `PrintLL` change to `Print`? list has certain connotations. I'd probably want to steer clear of the word 'list'.

(I will return and add in further suggestiosn for improvement when I get a proper opportunity - and where relevant will show tests.).

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick look on your source code, it suggests that you are trying to implement a **singly linked list**. Is that correct? Based on that I disagree with the suggestions in the previous posts to use the [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx). The reason is that [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) implements a doubly Linked list, as one can read in the description or in the current .NET Core implementation. So if you are really looking for a single Linked List, the `LinkedList<T>` will not work for you. Please dont get me wrong, if you can also use a doubly linked list then go for it and use LinkedList in the Collections, but it is important to be aware of the differences between a singly linked list and a doubly linked list.

Based on what I see in the source code above, I recommend the following refactorings:

- Your "MyLinkedList" class is actually the "Node" in your linked List and should be named so. Please also try to use the naming conventions as they make your source code much more readable.
- I recommend the following "deleteOdd" method:

  ```
  ListNode current = head;

  while (current != null)
  {

      if (current.data % 2 != 0)
      {
          if(current.previous != null) // As the list is non circular, if current!=head
          {
              current.previous.next = current.next;
          }
          else
          {
             setListHead(current.next); // current is your head
          }
      }

      current = current.next;
  }
  ```

  - Try to make your add functions run properly and use them for your test data. The best way to set up test preconditions is of course using Unit tests.

Comment: Thank s a lot for the insights 0x51ba. This is answers the logic part of my question.